# Implementation of the Baum-Welch algorithm for HMM parameter estimation

Tags: probability, algorithms, machine-learning

In order to learn HMM thoroughly, I am implementing (in Matlab) the various algorithms for the basic questions of HMM. I've implemented the Viterbi, posterior-decoding, and the forward-backward algorithms successfully, but I have one question regarding the Baum-Welch algorithm for the estimation of the HMM parameters.

In the [classic paper by Rabiner](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Bayes/rabiner.pdf), the re-estimation of the transition probabilities matrix is given in equation (95), in terms of the scaled forward ($\hat\alpha$) and backward ($\hat\beta$) variables. The numerator is
$$
\sum_{t=1}^{T-1}\hat\alpha_t(i)a_{ij}b_j(O_{t+1})\hat\beta_{t+1}(j)
$$
where $a$ is the transition matrix, $b$ the observation matrix, and $O$ the observation sequence.

However, in [this HMM project guide](http://www.ece.ucsb.edu/Faculty/Rabiner/ece259/speech%20recognition%20course/term%20projects/HMM%20Project.pdf), section 4.4, (also by Rabiner), as well is in the implementation in Matlab's function `hmmtrain.m` (from the statistics toolbox), there is an extra factor of $1/c_{t+1}$ in the numerator, where $c_t$ is the scaling factor of time step $t$. I followed the algebra of the definition of the re-estimation of $a$, and I still fail to understand where this factor is coming from. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If this question is more appropriate in http://stats.stackexchange.com/, please tell me how to migrate the question

Comment: Is the factor $1/c_{t+1}$ also present in the denominator?

Comment: Basically yes, since the denominator is just normalizing the rows of the re-estimated `a` matrix, it is a sum over the rows, so it is just a sum over `j` of the numerator.

Comment: And one can multiply the numerator and the denominator by a same factor, for example by $1/c_{t+1}$, without changing the only relevant quantity, which is their ratio. Does this remark answer your question?

Comment: Nevertheless, in the project guide mentioned in my question it is absent from the denominator (which is defined as $\sum_t\hat\alpha_t(i)\hat\beta_t(i)$

Comment: @ Didier Piau: No, since there is summation over $t$, and the factor depends on $t$ so it is not simply cancelled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that in Rabiner's paper, $\hat\beta_t$ is scaled with $c_t$, wile in the implementation I was looking at it is scaled with $c_{t+1}$. This introduces a "shift" in the scaling time index, so a factor of $c_{t+1}$ must be introduced in order to get the $C_tD_{t+1}$ term which you can cancel from both the numerator and the denominator, since it is not dependent on $t$.

With this scaling convention, equation (97) in Rabiner's paper becomes
$$
\hat\beta_{t+1}(j)=\left[\prod_{s=t+2}^Tc_s\right]\beta_{t+1}(j)=D_{t+2}\beta_{t+1}(j)=D_{t+1}\beta_{t+1}(j)/c_{t+1}
$$